# In-app Billing class not found

Tags: android, in-app-billing

i used in-app billing in my application. There is only single button onto which i assign code everything goes fine but as i click on button it gives me error in my log i dont understand what went wrong can somebody help me .........

My log File

```
 07-12 23:24:54.148: I/dalvikvm(26904): Could not find method com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.consumePurchase, referenced from method com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.consume
07-12 23:24:54.148: W/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 4293: Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;.consumePurchase (ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
07-12 23:24:54.148: D/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x008d
07-12 23:24:54.156: I/dalvikvm(26904): Could not find method com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getBuyIntent, referenced from method com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow
07-12 23:24:54.156: W/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 4294: Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;.getBuyIntent (ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
07-12 23:24:54.156: D/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: replacing opcode 0x78 at 0x002a
07-12 23:24:54.156: I/dalvikvm(26904): Could not find method com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getPurchases, referenced from method com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases
07-12 23:24:54.156: W/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 4295: Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;.getPurchases (ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
07-12 23:24:54.156: D/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x004a
07-12 23:24:54.156: I/dalvikvm(26904): Could not find method com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails, referenced from method com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.querySkuDetails
07-12 23:24:54.156: W/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 4296: Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;.getSkuDetails (ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
07-12 23:24:54.156: D/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0038
07-12 23:24:54.156: D/SIAPv3(26904): IAB helper created.
07-12 23:24:54.156: D/SIAPv3(26904): Starting in-app billing setup.
07-12 23:24:54.156: I/dalvikvm(26904): Could not find method com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub.asInterface, referenced from method com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper$1.onServiceConnected
07-12 23:24:54.156: W/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4292: Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub;.asInterface (Landroid/os/IBinder;)Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;
07-12 23:24:54.156: D/dalvikvm(26904): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
07-12 23:24:54.179: D/SIAPv3(26904): Billing service connected.
07-12 23:24:54.179: D/AndroidRuntime(26904): Shutting down VM
07-12 23:24:54.179: W/dalvikvm(26904): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b9d2a0)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper$1.onServiceConnected(IabHelper.java:228)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1097)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1114)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-12 23:24:54.187: E/AndroidRuntime(26904):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 23:24:54.211: D/dalvikvm(26904): GC_CONCURRENT freed 183K, 10% free 7854K/8647K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 29ms
07-12 23:24:54.211: D/AbsListView(26904): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
07-12 23:24:54.211: I/MotionRecognitionManager(26904):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@423a7560
07-12 23:24:54.218: D/AbsListView(26904): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
07-12 23:24:54.218: I/MotionRecognitionManager(26904):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@4235be38
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the in app billing aidl file?

`IINAppBillingService.aidl`

Are you using eclipse or android studoi or intelliJ or what?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use google play in your project,if you do this,you need do

1. [desc how to add google aidl to your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7cdj.png)
2. and clean rebuild